# First Inizialization of VBO. Does it matter where to bind?

Tags: opengl, buffer, vbo

Say i want just to create and fill a buffer.

```
GLuint ret;
glGenBuffers(1,&ret);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ret);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,size,data,usage);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
```

Does it really matter which target i use in the two calls? (Of course they must be the same).
For example: can i fill the buffer writing to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target while it's binded on it and later on in the code bind the sane buffer to the `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER` target and use it's data for filling a uniform block with `glBindBufferRange`?

Comment: Nothing in what you've shown is a "VAO".

Comment: I assume the OP means VBO based on the code sample

Comment: yes, i meant vbo, title edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter; any target should work. I've created buffers with targets matching the intended usage before and it made no difference.

I guess an OpenGL implementation (i.e. driver) could allocate memory differently depending on the target passed but I've not seen evidence of this.

Also, the newer [`glNamedBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) which does the same thing as `glBufferData` without requiring a previous `glBindBuffer` call does not have a `target` parameter. This hints strongly that the targets are interchangeable.